# Convert Option[String] to Option[Path]

Tags: scala, path, option-type

I have a functionality with a field of type Option[Path], then the data type of this field changed to Option[String].
I would like to rewrite this functionality without using matching, is that possible to do so?

The way it used to look like with **samplePath: Option[Path]**

```
samplePath.fold(new File(getResource("sample").getPath))(_.toFile)
```

The way it looks like with **samplePath: Option[String]**

```
  def transformToPath(path: Option[String]): Option[Path] = {
    path match {
      case Some(st) => Some(Paths.get(st))
      case None => None
    }
  }

transformToPath(samplePath).fold(new File(getResource("sample").getPath))(_.toFile)
```

Comment: `samplePath.flatMap(str => Try(Paths.get(str)).toOption).fold(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most naive solution would be to `.map` the path:

```
def transformToPath(path: Option[String]): Option[Path] =
   path.map(path => Paths.get(path))
```

A better way would be to wrap the inner expression with a `Try[A]`:

```
def transformToPath(path: Option[String]): Option[Path] =
   path.flatMap(path => Try(Paths.get(path)).toOption)
```

Note that this will not signal an error occurred in `Paths.get` (which can throw an exception). Ideally, we should also propagate that to the caller:

```
def transformToPath(path: Option[String]): Either[Throwable, Option[Path]] =
  path.fold[Either[Throwable, Option[Path]]](Right(None))(
    path => Try(Paths.get(path)).map(Option(_)).toEither
  )
```

Now, in case `Paths.get` throws we get a `Left` with an `Exception`.

Perhaps even better would be eliminating the `Option[String]` input an requiring a strict `String` to be passed in, which helps us avoid the redundant `Option[Path]` wrapper and return a direct `Path` object in case we successfully constructed it:

```
def transformToPath(path: String): Either[Throwable, Path] =
  Try(Paths.get(path)).toEither
```

Now, this would require the external caller `.map` over the Option[String]` before calling this method:

```
val result = Option(someStringFromJavaLand).map(transformToPath)
```

Comment: What if I don't need to throw an exception? There are also cases when String returns null that is why I used an option

Comment: @Cassie You're not actually throwing an exception, it's `Paths.get` that may throw. If you don't need that, you can use the first option I showed you.